# Integrate external service with Form Type on symfony (Dynamic Form)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, event-handling

I have a dynamic form in symfony. currently i have a external service where the data exist this services provided a way to render a form for data but i need integrate with my bussines logic into my app.

for solve this problem I implements a annotation and a CustomType. the annotation is simple holder for the name of the table in the external service

in my app i have a entity

```
/**
 * Person
 *
 * @ORM\Table("person")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @EService("person_data")
 */
class Person extends AbstractEntityEService
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
   private $id;

   /**/
}

/**
 * AbstractEntityEService
 *
 */
abstract AbstractEntityEService
{
   /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="uuid", type="string")
    */
   protected $uuid;

   /**
    * Holder for the data 
   protected $data;

   /* setters and getters... */
}
```

the external service provide a `uuid` when i store data, with this `uuid` i can print the fields in my view and with this uuid i can update the data.

here is my CustomType

```
class ExternalType extends AbstractType {

    /**
     * @var Reader
     */
    private $reader;

    /**
     * @var ExternalService
     */
    private $ts;

    public function __construct(Reader $reader, ExternalService $ts){
        $this->reader = $reader;
        $this->ts = $ts;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function(FormEvent $event) use ($options) {
                $annotation = $this->reader->getClassAnnotation(
                    new \ReflectionClass($options['class']),
                    'MyBundle\Lib\Annotation\EServiceAnnotation'
                );

                // this is only form a empty form
                if (null === $event->getData()) {
                    // here get the annotated value from entity and get a uuid
                    $event->setData($this->ts->getForm($annotation->getformName()));
                }

                $event->getForm()->getParent()->add('data', 'collection', array(
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'label' => false
                ));
            });
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver
            ->setDefaults(array(
                'required'       => false,
                'error_bubbling' => true
            ))
            ->setRequired(array(
                'class',
            ));
    }

    /**     
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'external';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'hidden';
    }
}
```

this is the template for the CustomType

```
{% block external_widget %}
    {% spaceless %} 
        <div data-form-name="{{ form.parent.vars.name }}" data-form-uuid="{{uuid}}"></div>
        {% set type = type|default('hidden') %}
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock external_widget %}
```

i register my ExternalType like service for use into my main form PersonType

```
class AsociacionType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('uuid', 'external', array('class' => $options['data_class']));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Person'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_bundle_person';
    }
}
```

and at the last i use the doctrine.event_subscriber

- `postLoad` : for fill the data property in my Entities using the uuid for call external service
- `prePersist`: for persist the data sent by users into the external service
- `preUpdate`: for update the data sent by user into the external service

Here the events

```
public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    if ($entity instanceof AbstractEntityEService && null !== $entity->getUuid())
    {
        $t = $this->externalService->get($entity->getUuid());
        $entity->setData((array)$t->getData());
    }
}

public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    if ($entity instanceof AbstractEntityEService) {
        $t = $this->externalService->persist($entity->getData(), $entity->getUuid());
        $entity->setUuid($t->getUuid());
    }
}

public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $this->prePersist($args);
}
```

The new and create works fine. but when i'm going to update the data for a unknown reason **the `preUpdate` event never is called**. I think it is because the form does not mean that the data has changed. **I need to know how to tell to Symfony `the form has changed`**

Comment: Can you post your event subscribers? Are you recomputing the changeset in the preUpdate?

Comment: the `preUpdate` never is called